# Auto fill dropdown in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am looking for ASP.NET Auto fill dropdown. I am not planning to use AJAX toolkit. I am looking for something with webservices and jquery combination. Does any one have any sample or open source tool

Answer (score 1):

There is an autcomplete drop down plugin on the jquery site: [jQuery Autocomplete tools](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

The [demo](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/) for the plugin shows an option to get the data remotely. Its example is in php but you could do the same thing using a webservice in ASP.NET

```
$("#YourControl").autocomplete("PathToWebService", {
    // autocomplete options
});
```

Comment: thx for the response. what i am looking is dropdown under the hood. when the user start typing i want to call server side method and real time poplate the values.

Comment: @user171523 There is an url option for this plugin that would allow you to go get the data.